# ConcurrentHashmap cause infinite loop in Java 8

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

The following code causes CPU usage to reach 100%. The infinite loop occurred while doing load tests. Normally it works fine. The jstack log shows infinite loop at `map.put(i,current);`

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at
com.wk.search.utils.FragmentsHighlightUtis.fragmentHiglight(FragmentsHighlightUtis.java:51)
```

Line 51 in file `FragmentsHighlightUtis.java` is

```java
map.put(i,current);
```

```java
public static String fragmentHiglight(String body,List<String> highlightField) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    int size = 100;
    int segment = body.length()/size;
    int maxSegment = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= segment; i++) {
        map.put(i,0);
        String bulk="";
        if (segment > 0) {
            bulk = bodySubstring(body, size, segment, i);
        }else{
            bulk = body;
        }
        for (String key : highlightField) {
            int index = bulk.indexOf(key);
            while (index >= 0) {
                if (index >= 0) {
                    int current = map.get(i)+1;
                    if(current>map.get(maxSegment)){
                        maxSegment = i;
                    }
                    map.put(i,current);
                }
                index = bulk.indexOf(key,index+1);
            }
        }
    }
    String bodyFrag = bodySubstring(body, size, segment, maxSegment);
    String fragmentHiglight = "";
    for (String s : highlightField) {
        fragmentHiglight= bodyFrag.replaceAll(s, "<font class=\\\"titleHL\\\">"+ s+"</font>");
        bodyFrag = fragmentHiglight;
    }
    return fragmentHiglight;
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to debug this code in an IDE like IntelliJ. I would start with the simple case where `body.length()` is less than 100 so bulk = body. Does that get stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: it make sense. thank you. let me give a try

Comment: just tired .it does no seem possible as indexof will become -1 if less than 100

Comment: the infinite loop occured when we doing load tests. normally it works fine.so it's hard test this in intellij

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to help you by just inspecting the code. What the code does depends on input arguments. I'm confident you can figure it out using a debugger.

Comment: What are the numbers/sizes/lengths in you load test. The loops are guaranteed to terminate afaikt, but if key is the empty string, and depending of what bodySubstring does, it may just take ages. I would put a long counter into the inner loop and log index and key and whatever every million iterations or so. Btw, why ConcurrentHashMap? There is nothing concurrent in this method.

Comment: so it's due to key's empty string, and then end up with infinite loop?

Comment: No infinite loop, but it may take long.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `ConcurrentHashMap` at all because at any time you access only two values of it: `map.get(maxSegment)` and `map.get(i)` - but you could easily store these two values in local variables:

```
public static String fragmentHiglight(String body,List<String> highlightField) {
    int size = 100;
    int segment = body.length()/size;
    int maxSegment = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= segment; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        String bulk;
        if (segment > 0) {
            bulk = bodySubstring(body, size, segment, i);
        } else {
            bulk = body;
        }
        for (String key : highlightField) {
            int index = bulk.indexOf(key);
            while (index >= 0) {
                count++;
                if (count > maxCount) {
                    maxSegment = i;
                    maxCount = count;
                }
                index = bulk.indexOf(key,index+1);
            }
        }
    }
    String bodyFrag = bodySubstring(body, size, segment, maxSegment);
    String fragmentHiglight = "";
    for (String s : highlightField) {
        fragmentHiglight= bodyFrag.replaceAll(s, "<font class=\\\"titleHL\\\">"+ s+"</font>");
        bodyFrag = fragmentHiglight;
    }
    return fragmentHiglight;
}
```

Comment: thank you. this makes sense. do i need to add and check if key is empty string?

Comment: @DAPG I'm not sure what you mean with "check if key is empty string".